# Rounding down a float number to 2 decimal points in java

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have a variable x that is 11.885, when I round this to 2 decimal points I want it to give me 11.88 but it won't work and I can't figure it out. I won't be using import or anything but just can't figure out a way to round this number down.

What I originally used:

```
double x = 11.885     
double y = (double) Math.round(x * 100.0) / 100.0;
```

but this gives me 11.89. I also need this without printing it since I will be using this rounded number in my code.

Comment: Multiply by 100, then cast to int, then divide by 100.

Comment: You can also use `NumberFormat`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of [`Math.round(double)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round-double-), use [`Math.floor(double)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#floor-double-) like

```
double x = 11.885;
double y = Math.floor(x * 100) / 100.0;
System.out.println(y);
```

I get (as requested)

```
11.88
```

Answer (score 0):

Try BigDecimal It has a lot of helpful features like this.

```
double x = 11.885;
BigDecimal y = BigDecimal.valueOf(x);
y.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP)
```